# aggregate over a list in R

Tags: r, loops, aggregate, mean, lapply

I am looking to find the mean of values in a list of dataframes.

Each dataframe (there are 70 something) has a list of dates and values.  I want to find the mean of the values per date. Here is a snippet.

Dataframe is named `Quantimodo`.

```
Measurement.Event.Time  Variable.Name   Value
30/11/2016 1:48 Activeness  2
30/11/2016 8:57 Activeness  1
3/12/2016 1:21  Activeness  2
4/12/2016 10:02 Activeness  2
5/12/2016 10:01 Activeness  3
8/12/2016 2:21  Activeness  2
9/12/2016 7:41  Activeness  2
12/12/2016 19:35    Activeness  2
14/12/2016 16:13    Activeness  1
15/12/2016 15:36    Activeness  2
15/12/2016 18:22    Activeness  3
17/12/2016 8:50 Activeness  3
18/12/2016 9:15 Activeness  3
18/12/2016 17:46    Activeness  2
10/01/2017 18:02    Activeness  1
15/01/2017 11:03    Activeness  4
26/02/2017 14:31    Activeness  3
1/03/2017 12:04 Activeness  2
2/03/2017 9:58  Activeness  2
28/11/2016 8:00 Alertness   4
29/11/2016 8:00 Alertness   4

Quantimodo$Measurement.Event.Time <- as.Date(Quantimodo$Measurement.Event.Time, "%d/%m/%Y")

Quanti_list = split(Quantimodo, f = Quantimodo$Variable.Name)

Quantireduce<-Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = "Measurement.Event.Time", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE),
       list(Quanti_list))
```

What do I do next? From what I think, I have lists of each Variable.Name.  I want to find the mean of each Value.

I've looked into for loops, aggregate and lapply, but I can't adapt what I've found on Stackoverflow.  Am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `list` of `data.frame`s.  Then you can rbind them together with a grouping variable and then do a group by `mean` i.e. `library(dplyr); bind_rows(lst, .id = 'grp') %>% group_by(grp, date) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Value))`

Comment: What you say works.  Maybe I asked the wrong question.  Is there a way to find the mean of each variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` makes it easy to work with one large data.table (as long as data structures permit) instead of a list of data frames.

Let's assume `Quantimodo` is the large data.frame and we want to compute the mean for each date and each variable. With `data.table` we can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Quantimodo)[, mean(Value), by = .(as.Date(Measurement.Event.Time), Variable.Name)]
#       as.Date Variable.Name  V1
# 1: 2016-11-30    Activeness 1.5
# 2: 2016-12-03    Activeness 2.0
# 3: 2016-12-04    Activeness 2.0
# ...
#15: 2017-03-01    Activeness 2.0
#16: 2017-03-02    Activeness 2.0
#17: 2016-11-28     Alertness 4.0
#18: 2016-11-29     Alertness 4.0
```

Note that the conversion of `Measurement.Event.Time` is done *on the fly* within the grouping (`by = ...`).

In case you have a list of data.frames with identical structure, I suggest to use `rbindlist()` to create one large data.table which can be processed in one piece. For instance

```
rbindlist(Quanti_list, idcol = "id")[
  , mean(Value), by = .(id, as.Date(Measurement.Event.Time), Variable.Name)]
#            id    as.Date Variable.Name  V1
# 1: Activeness 2016-11-30    Activeness 1.5
# 2: Activeness 2016-12-03    Activeness 2.0
# 3: Activeness 2016-12-04    Activeness 2.0
#15: Activeness 2017-03-01    Activeness 2.0
#16: Activeness 2017-03-02    Activeness 2.0
#17:  Alertness 2016-11-28     Alertness 4.0
#18:  Alertness 2016-11-29     Alertness 4.0
```

Note that parameter `idcol = "id"` adds an id column which identifies the list element of which each row originates (In this case, it is identical to `Variable.Name`). `id` is used here in the grouping for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you looked at `aggregate` it would be useful if you could explain why I didn't work for you.

> I've looked into for loops, aggregate and lapply, but I can't adapt
>   what I've found on Stackoverflow. Am I going about this all wrong?

Broadly speaking, finding means, or any other aggregate values for that matter, of a variable across data sets stored within a list can be achieved in the following manner.

```
# Copy / paste for the provided data
dfA = read.delim(pipe("pbpaste"), sep="", header=TRUE, row.names = NULL)
dfB <- dfA

lapply(X = list(dfA, dfB),
       FUN = function(x) {
           aggregate(x = x, by = list(unique.values = x$row.names), mean)
       })
```

This would produce:

```
[[1]]
   unique.values row.names Measurement.Event.Time Variable.Name Value
1      1/03/2017        NA                     NA            NA   2.0
2     10/01/2017        NA                     NA            NA   1.0
3     12/12/2016        NA                     NA            NA   2.0
4     14/12/2016        NA                     NA            NA   1.0
```

if you want to merge data later you could encapsulate `lapply` in `do.call`: `do.call("rbind", lapply(...))`.

---

*`row.names` reflect your first column here as I've quickly copy/pasted the provided snippet. I also didn't change the column types.*